# How do I tag textfiles with hunpos in nltk?

Tags: python, nltk, corpus, pos-tagger

Can someone help me with the syntax for hunpos tagging a corpus in nltk?

1. What do I import for the [`hunpos.HunPosTagger` module](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.tag.hunpos.HunposTagger-class.html)?
2. How do I HunPosTag the corpus? See the code below.

---

```
import nltk 
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader  
from nltk.corpus.util import LazyCorpusLoader  

corpus_root = './'  
reader = PlaintextCorpusReader (corpus_root, '.*')  

ntuen = LazyCorpusLoader ('ntumultien', PlaintextCorpusReader, reader)  
ntuen.fileids()  
isinstance (ntuen, PlaintextCorpusReader)  


# So how do I hunpos tag `ntuen`? I can't get the following code to work.
# please help me to correct my python syntax errors, I'm new to python 
# but i really need this to work. sorry
##from nltk.tag import hunpos.HunPosTagger
ht = HunPosTagger('english.model')
for sentence in ntu.sent() ##looping through the no. of sentence
     ht.tag(ntusent()[i])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import nltk 
from nltk.tag.hunpos import HunposTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

corpus = "so how do i hunpos tag my ntuen ? i can't get the following code to work."
#please help me to correct my python syntax errors, i'm new to python 
#but i really need this to work. sorry
##from nltk.tag import hunpos.HunPosTagger
ht = HunposTagger('en_wsj.model')
print ht.tag(word_tokenize(corpus))
```

I feel like the problem is you're not tokenizing the words, but there are other reasons the code may not work (it's HunposTagger, not HunPosTagger).  I made this simplified example from your question.  If you have any more questions please post a comment.

I got everything from here: http://code.google.com/p/hunpos/

> python hunpos.py
>
> [('so', 'RB'), ('how', 'WRB'), ('do', 'VBP'), ('i', 'FW'), ('hunpos', 'NN'), ('tag', 'NN'), ('my', 'PRP$'), ('ntuen', 'NN'), ('?', '.'), ('i', 'FW'), ('ca', 'MD'), ("n't", 'RB'), ('get', 'VB'), ('the', 'DT'), ('following', 'JJ'), ('code', 'NN'), ('to', 'TO'), ('work', 'VB'), ('.', '.')]

Comment: i managed to code it into the nltk. i have to split each sentence into a new line. thanks. then run this command ht.tag(file.readline().split())