# In python nltk I am trying to get parts of speech of a word by using pos_tag. but I am getting inaccurate output? Tell me the better tagger?

Tags: python, nltk

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenizer

w="cat"
word=nltk.word_tokenize(w)
print nltk.pos_tag(word)

output:[('cat','IN')]
```

but cat is a noun,but it returns as IN(Conjunction).

Answer (score 0):

POS tagging doesn't really work well out of sentence context. Feed a whole sentence to `pos_tag` instead of a single word, then try again. If it doesn't work, use `nltk.download()` to fetch a better POS tagging model and run that.

If you need all the POS tags for a single word, try WordNet:

```
In [9]: nltk.corpus.wordnet.synsets('cat')
Out[9]: 
[Synset('cat.n.01'),
 Synset('guy.n.01'),
 Synset('cat.n.03'),
 Synset('kat.n.01'),
 Synset("cat-o'-nine-tails.n.01"),
 Synset('caterpillar.n.02'),
 Synset('big_cat.n.01'),
 Synset('computerized_tomography.n.01'),
 Synset('cat.v.01'),
 Synset('vomit.v.01')]
```

(As you can see, you may have to filter these.)

Comment: but my requirement is I will give only one word  and i need its appropriate parts of  speech.

Comment: Ya. I already used that. I am getting proper output. But can you tell me for how many word the synsets() method will work. and can you provide how synsets() method works?

Comment: you can take a look at the basics of WordNet synsets in nltk here: http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the `hunpos` with the pretrained model, `en_wsj.model`:

```
$ gzip -d en_wsj.model.gz 
$ wget https://hunpos.googlecode.com/files/en_wsj.model.gz
$ python
>>> from nltk.tag.hunpos import HunposTagger
>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
>>> sent = "cat"
>>> ht = HunposTagger('en_wsj.model')
>>> print ht.tag(word_tokenize(sent))
[('cat', 'NN')]
```

see [How do I tag textfiles with hunpos in nltk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088448/how-to-i-tag-textfiles-with-hunpos-in-nltk), hunpos always do much better than the default `pos_tag` in NLTK.